# Why is the argument type incorrect (it is int when it should be int *)?

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C which scans values and prints the values out in order of 'team 1 value 1, team 2 value 1, team 1 value 2, team 2 value 2', etc. 
I keep getting an error on the line 'printf("Team 1 weighs: %i\n", team1);' with the message 'format specifies type int but the argument has type 'int *' and I can't figure out why. I think it might have something to do with the arrays.
I'd appreciate any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    printf("How many members of each team are there?\n");

    int team1 [] = {110, 113, 112, 117};
    int team2 [] = {106, 102, 121, 111};

    scanf("%i", &team1[4]);
    printf("How much do the players of team 1 weigh?\n");
    scanf("%i", &team1[4]);

    printf("Team 1 weighs: %i\n", team1);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to print the values that I entered in when it requested user input, e.g. "How much do the players of team 1 weigh?" My answer: 43, 25, 64, 35.
Print "Team 1 weighs: 43, 25, 64, 35".

Comment: `[4]` refers to the fifth element of the array.

Comment: Its time to learn about loops

Comment: In `C` array index starts from zero. And this `int team1 [] = {110, 113, 112, 117};` allows you to use index from `0` to `3`. There is no `team1[4]`. Causing array element out of bounds is undefined behavior.

Comment: Related: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: @P.W *"the fifth element"*  Multipass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`team1` is not an `int`, it is an array of `int` of size `4`. Arrays *"decay"* to pointers when passed to functions, which explains why you're seeing that error message.

You need to individually print all elements, for example with a `for` loop.

---

Your `scanf` calls are also incorrect - you are reading a single elements outside of the bounds of the `team1` array, which is undefined behavior. You need to scan each element with a loop.